# strcat пропускает символы?

Tags: c++

План действий такой записано где-то в глобальную переменную G_processedText текстовое сообщение, в этой функции я присоединяю к этой переменной переменную alphabet(пока все без нареканий), потом через цикл делаю отсечку повторяющихся символов(с помощью функции strcat) в переменную saveSymbols и вот здесь происходят странные вещи: сначала строки соединятся, но потом от G_processedText в результате цикла может отъесть одну букву

```
#pragma argsused
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#define SIZE 250
#define SIZE_2 5
using namespace std;
//Прототипы функций
void keyWord();
void initializeMatrix();
//Глобальные переменные
char G_processedText[SIZE];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    initializeMatrix();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} 
    void initializeMatrix()
    {
        ///cout << "Matrix: " << G_processedText << endl;
        char matrix[SIZE_2][SIZE_2];
        char saveSymbols[SIZE_2];
        char alphabet[] = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char j, p;
        int i, k;
        k = 0;
        ///Объединение ключа и алфавита
        strcat(G_processedText, alphabet);
        cout << "\nMatrix: " << endl;
        for (i = 0; i <= strlen(G_processedText); i++)
        {
            p = G_processedText[i];
            if(!strchr(saveSymbols, p))
            {
                saveSymbols[k] = p;
                k += 1;
            }
        }
        cout << saveSymbols;
```

Итогом всех действий должна быть строка без повторяющихся символов

Comment: Проверьте, что не выходите за границы массивов. При записи `saveSymbols[k] = p;` проверяйте, что `k < SIZE_2`.

Comment: а я не выхожу за пределы 250символов

Comment: У `saveSymbols` размер 5.

Comment: точно, изменил на 250, все выводится правильно но в конце после строки выводится символьный мусор

Comment: Почему не строго меньше, а меньше или равно тут?

           `for (i = 0; i <= strlen(G_processedText); i++)`

Comment: опечатался с больше или равно, иногда борлэнд автоматически подставляет в конструкцию for все элементы

Answer (score 1):

Написал так:

```
char saveSymbols[SIZE] = "";
```

И мусор исчез, попутный вопрос, а какие еще способы очистки есть?
Такой вариант компилятор отказался обрабатывать

```
char saveSymbols[SIZE] = {};
```

Comment: memset(saveSymbols, 0, sizeof(saveSymbols))

Comment: `char saveSymbols[SIZE] = {0};`